# MySQL DISTINCT/GROUP BY with MAX()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

PROBLEM: I'm trying to pull a list of all records, `DISTINCT` by the Name using the highest Added timestamp number for that name. I use all results columns in a PHP `fetch`.

Have a simple database with records as follow:

```
---ID-------NAME-------VERSION-----------ADDED-------
|  500   |  TheSame   |    1    |  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
|  501   |  TheSame   |    2    |  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |           
|  502   |  SameName  |    30   |  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
|  503   |  SameName  |    31   |  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

`ID` is auto-increment. Tried a ton of different things and can get the `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to work fine, but I end up with the lowest record (ex: `SameName` record #502 and version #30, when it should be #503 and version #31.

No `JOIN` or anything going on here, so this should be pretty simple.

Comment: Post your best shot so far.  Use [edit].

Comment: [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) seems a similar problem and they _do_ use JOIN. But to be honest, I also think there must be a possibility to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this try(Possible way to get the latest-version number:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS VERSION
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY NAME
```

If above, does not meet the requirement, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        NAME, ID, VERSION, ADDED
    FROM 
        TABLENAME
    ORDER BY 
        NAME, VERSION DESC, ID, ADDED 
) myAlias
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: Updated the answer.... @user3223880

Comment: The latter gives the max. version but a random (?) timestamp -- not the corresponding one.

Comment: It will work fine now, thanks to point me out @PerlDog